# Sum of numbers in a single cell, but keep format?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet where I'm keeping track of different pieces of data throughout the day using a certain format. I have a column for each day of the week. I'd like to not have to worry about adding up everything from everyday for the rest of the time I am keeping track of this data. Is there a code to accomplish this? The format is as follows.

```
   Monday  Tuesday   etc.
   X/X/X    X/X/X
```

I want to add all of these numbers up, but keep the format of X/X/X. Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated, I haven't the slightest clue on how to accomplish this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
function sumofsplits() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getRange("B23:H23");
  const vs=rg.getValues()[0];
  let sum=0;
  vs.forEach(e=>sum+=e.split(',').reduce((a,c)=>{a+=Number(c);return a;},0));
  let o='The sum is ' + sum;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(o),"Sum of Splits");
}
```

You can use the below function with a two dimensional range:

```
function sumofsplits() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sr=23;//start row
  const rg=sh.getRange(sr,2,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,7);
  const vs=rg.getValues();
  let sum=0;
  vs.forEach(r=>r.forEach(e=>sum+=e.split(',').reduce((a,c)=>{a+=Number(c);return a;},0)));
  let o='The sum is ' + sum;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(o),"Sum of Splits");
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper thank you for the answer, but are you able to give me some more information? Where am I putting this code? Do I need to replace anything in here with a cell location?

Comment: Well what cell has the comma separated values?

Comment: Cells B23:H23 have the values.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be in your question

Comment: Okay I summed over that range now